# divs displaying correctly in dreamweaver, but not browse

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm hoping someone can point me the right way. When I view my site in Dreamweaver, all of my divs line up correctly. That is to say, the text sits on the background next to the menu div. However, when I test in a browser, the text sits at the bottom, below the background image.

http://jsfiddle.net/sodisarmingdarling/Pr5AQ/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
        html, body, .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding:0;
            background-image:url(Background.gif); 
            background-repeat:no-repeat;

        }


        .menu {
    padding: 70px 10px;
    float: left;

        }

        li{
            padding: 10px 20px;
            margin: 0px 0;
            list-style-type: none;
            border: 0px;
        }

        .content{
            padding: 130px 10px;
            float: left;
            font-family: "Letter Gothic Std Bold";
            font-size: 16 pt;
            color: #99CCFF; 
        }

</style>        

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">



      <div class="menu">

            <ul>
                <li><a href = "#" ><img src="images/DarkLayout_03.gif" width="166" height="66" /></a></li>
                <li><a href = "#"><img src="images/DarkLayout_06.gif" width="166" height="66" /></a></li>
<li><a href="mailto:swy5105@psu.edu"><img src="images/DarkLayout_08.gif" width="164" height="66" /></a></li>
                <li><a href = "notafilmnoirheroine.tumblr.com"><img src="images/DarkLayout_11.gif" width="164" height="66" /></a></li>
                <li><a href = "swy5105.tumblr.com"> <img src="images/DarkLayout_13.gif" width="166" height="66" /></a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>

      <div class="content">
            text text text
      </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

What I see in Dreamweaver:
[image]

What I get in the browser (tested in Safari, Chrome, and Mozilla):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS for the .content, change the **float** from left, to **none**.

Current CSS:

```
 .content{
        padding: 130px 10px;
        float: left;
        font-family: "Letter Gothic Std Bold";
        font-size: 16 pt;
        color: #99CCFF; 
    }
```

New CSS:

```
.content{
        padding: 130px 10px;
        float: none;
        font-family: "Letter Gothic Std Bold";
        font-size: 16 pt;
        color: #99CCFF; 
    }
```

Here is a jsFiddle of it (using random images in the html), http://jsfiddle.net/FvAW4/

Whilst the current CSS works for small text, with larger text it forces the text to go underneath everything. Changing it to none will solve this.

Design view is intended as a viewport for you to work in, and not as a browser to test in (even though most content is displayed the same in browsers). Dreamweaver has an option to enable the Design view to render it as though it were a browser, however. This option is called the "Live" view, and it is the tab next to the Design view tab.

I would suggest you get used to using Live view, as it's quick and easy to display the page. But remember, sometimes Dreamweaver renders the page contents differently to that of browsers.